# Does pip-tools and/or new resolver prevent upgrading to a subdependency version that breaks a primary dependency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pip-tools

I am using pip-tools 5.4.0, pip 20.3.1, and python3. I have looked at pip-tools source code and the pip blog post about the new resolver. I do not see an explicit answer to my question. If I run:

```
pipdeptree
flake8==3.8.4
  - mccabe [required: >=0.6.0,<0.7.0, installed: 0.6.1]
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.6.0a1,<2.7.0, installed: 2.6.0]
  - pyflakes [required: >=2.2.0,<2.3.0, installed: 2.2.0
...
```

If I run `pip-compile --upgrade`, are there internal constraints in pip-tools or dependency-checking in the new pip resolver that will prevent subdependencies from upgrading beyond their constraints, e.g., mccabe upgrading to 0.7.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Original pip-tools author here (although today's maintenance is now happening by the [JazzBand collective](https://github.com/jazzband/))

Yes, all top-level constraints (the constraints you put in your `requirements.in` file yourself), as well as any secondary constraints (the constraints required by each concrete package version that gets subsequently resolved) all form one big "constraint space". pip-tools' resolver will always resolve versions within that constraint space, or throw an error.

In your example, the version of `mccabe` that `flake8==3.8.4` requires will thus be respected and as a result the version of `mccabe` that gets resolved will never be `0.7` or higher. (That's the very purpose of `pip-tools`.)

At the time of writing this post, 3.8.4 is flake8's highest version. If, however, you specified `flake8` (without any version constraints) in your `requirements.in` file, then *it* may get upgraded to, say, 3.9.0 in the future. That future version may specify a wider range for `mccabe`, like `mccabe>=0.6,<0.8` or something. In that case, the result of `pip-compile --upgrade` *may* upgrade `mccabe` to 0.7.0 of course.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge (which is several years of using pip-tools), pip-tools will always give you a stable tree so long as you do then install dependencies only from the "locked" requirements file.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "install from... locked...", I assume you mean running `pip-sync requirements.txt`?

Comment: Or `pip install -r requirements.txt` if you don't mind the extra packages that `pip-sync` might remove.